# Rewrite virtual subdomain to subfolder and keep original url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I searched across the web for a few days now but I didn't found any anwser to my question. This is what I want to do:

Every user on my site recieves a personal subdomain like http://username.domain.com.
Off course this is a virtual subdomain.

Now, I already set up a wildcard DNS A record, turn mod_rewrite ON and achieved to do this:

When somebody surfs to http:// anysubdomain.domain.com they are redirected to http:// www.domain.com/sub/index.php?var=anysubdomain. In the index.php there's a function that gets unique information based on the 'var' variable (the name of the subdomain).

What I want to do is when somebody is surfing to http:// anysubdomain.domain.com he's redirected to http:// www.domain.com/sub/index.php?var=anysubdomain (like it is now) but that the orginal URL (http:// anysubdomain.domain.com) is kept in the browser bar. So it really looks like every user has his own subdomain.

This is the htaccess file I currently use:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymlinks 


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)\.domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/sub/index.php?username=%2 [L]
```

I hope everything is clear, if not: ask and I provide more information!

Thanks in advance!

Yuri

Answer (score 0):

As long as all your subdomains and your main domain share the same document root, you can just get rid of the `http://www.domain.com` bit from your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)\.domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/index.php?username=%2 [L]
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use mod_proxy by adding the `P` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)\.domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/sub/index.php?username=%2 [L,P]
```

Though it's going to be much more efficient the first way.

Comment: How can I achieve to let all my subdomains have te same document root as the main domain? This is the current structure: 
/domains/domain.com/htdocs/
     - main domain
     - static

Because my subdomains are virtual (except for the static subdomain), they don't really have a root (or am I wrong?). 

When I get rid of the 'http://www.domain.com' in my .htaccess file, there's a 500 internal server error. Same when I use mod_proxy by adding the P flag.

Comment: @YuriH most likely all your subdomains have the same document root, if not you need to contact your hosting service's support.